# jQuery two childrens selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

It's possible to select two childrens without repeating parent element ?

```
$('section#id > h4, section#id > hr ').hide(); // OK

$('section#id > h4 + hr ').hide(); // Maybe ?
```

Thanks !

Comment: Not withing pure css selectors because there is no way to use `find()/children()` with css selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$('section#id').children('hr, h4').hide();
```

OR, [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
$('section#id').find('> hr, > h4').hide();
```

The `.find()` and `.children()` methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot !

In the same way it is possible css to avoid repeating the parent element

section#id > .test,
section#id > .test2{
background-color: red;
padding: 10px;
}

Comment: @JohnDoe, With simple CSS you can't

Answer (score 1):

Not within a selector itself.

However, you can use [**find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) after specifying the parent

```
$('section#id').find(' > h4,> hr ').hide();
```